# How can I add parent node to xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I add parent nodes for some child nodes using LINQ to XML?
How can I do this? I use Linq to xml and XDocument and XElement classes.

My result is:

```
<SLSRPT>
  <Header>
    ...
  </Header>
  <Detail>
    ...
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    ...
  </Detail>
</SLSRPT>
```

Finally, I want to add all Detail nodes into Details node. Below you see what I want to do:

```
<SLSRPT>
  <Header></Header>
<Details>
  <Detail>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
  </Detail>
<Details>

 <Header>
 </Header>
<Details>
  <Detail>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
  </Detail>
<Details>
</SLSRPT>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Are there any errors?

Comment: No I don't have any errors

document.Element("SLSRPT").Add(
                        new XElement("Detail",
                            new XElement("GTIN13", new XText(gtin13)),
                            new XElement("TransactionType", new XText(transactionType)),
                            new XElement("Quantity", new XText(quantity))
                            new XElement("Currency", new XText(currency)),
                            new XElement("TaxAmount", new XText(taxAmount)))
                        );

Comment: Why can't you just deserialize earlier XML into c# classes, then map data from old class structure to new class structure and then serialize ?